# Благополуччя чи добробут? Як правильно?

Tags: вживання-слів, калька

В [деяких джерелах](http://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/leksika/antisurzhik_pravilna_mova/5-1-0-244) слово *"благополуччя"* вважається калькою з російської, проте дане слово присутнє в [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/blaghopoluchchja).
*["Добробут"](http://sum.in.ua/s/dobrobut)* також є в словнику. Яке з слів доречніше використовувати, коли говоримо про забезпечене життя сім'ї?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подивимось у дорадянські словники, пошукаємо там слово благополуччя:

1. У [словнику Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/takogo-slova-net.html#show_point) такого слова немає.
2. У [словнику Кримського, Єфремова та ін.](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Krymskyi_Ahatanhel/Ros-ukr_akademichnyi_slovnyk/) такого слова немає.

В [етимолоґічному словнику радянської доби](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Boldyriev_Rostyslav/Etymolohichnyi_slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy_T_1_A_H/) також не бачимо цього слова.

Тому, хоч це слово і є у СУМі, не варто зловживати ним у мовленні, як вам і кажуть у "деяких джерелах", хоча вживати його, звісно, можна, бо воно вже прижилось у літературній мові, трапляється у романах як Загребельного, так і Дереша, у чому я пересвідчився на цьому сайті: [корпус української мови.](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx?l1=209)

Конкретно у цих романах: ["Намір."](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=33697) Любка Дереша і ["РІК 1014 ОСІНЬ. КОНСТАНТИНОПОЛЬ. ДИВО."](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=8190) Загребельного.